# javascript window.scrollto issue on Ipad

Tags: javascript, ios, ipad

I have a javascript that includes following line of code:

```
window.scrollto(x,y);
```

where x and y are the coordinates of the position where there should be scrolled.

This works fine on desktop computers but if I try it on an Ipad it does not scroll properly.

If I put an alert() statement before the window.scroll command it srolls properly.
Does anyone know of a fix?
Btw the ipad uses ios7.

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

do this:

> window.setTimeout(function() {window.scrollTo(x,y);}, 0);

also be aware of the case, scrollto is different to scrollTo in javascript.

Comment: Just a side comment: if I use this for iPad it works perfectly, on a normal browser it jumps to position 0,0 when executed. Is there a reason for this?

Comment: i think that depends on the coordinates you are passing, if not then i think best way is to filter and detect the platform use (just what i did to one of my project).

Comment: can you give me your check filter to see if an iPad is executing the script. Mine works fine on iPad simulator but bugs on the real iPad.

Comment: checks if the real iPad runs on the same os as the simulator. And try to put console.log or alert(if you don't have any debugger on real iPad) after window.scrollTo so you can track if the script is still executed in other events